# Google sheets, convert value from 1 column to another based on particular data in it

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

Let's say I have those values in the column:

```
w 1

w 2

w 3
```

I want to convert those values to

```
1

2

3
```

in another column.

So basically I need to convert the value "w x" to "x".
How do I do that?

Another example:
Let's say I have these values in a column:

```
World Level 1 (AR 0-19)

World Level 2 (AR 20-24)

World Level 3 (AR 25-29)
```

I want the result to be

```
1

2

3
```

Comment: Welcome. I believe your question could be oversimplified.  
Are data always, just one letter or more, one digit or more, have a space, also have words etc. Please share some more examples.

Comment: will add now, going to edit the post

Comment: *"Another example: Let's say I have..."* These are completely different than your first ones. Do these represent the pattern followed in your column? That is `2 words one digit (something)`?

Comment: Yes. I didn't mention it but there could also be the value "NA" for example which isn't part of the pattern and I don't want to do anything with it basically. Other than that value, yes it's a pattern

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to handle the issue.
I find the following the easiest ones.

For a single cell you can use

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\(.*\))|(\D)","")*1
```

For the whole column try

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A1:A7="",,REGEXREPLACE(A1:A7,"(\(.*\))|(\D)","")*1))
```

[image]

If you also want to get rid of the `#N/A` cells, please use

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF(A1:A7="",,REGEXREPLACE(A1:A7,"(\(.*\))|(\D)|""NA""","")*1)))
```

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Comment: How would you manage a cell value of `#N/A`?

Comment: @Tedinoz Please see the latest version of the formula.

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot! Definitely upvoted but it says it wont publicly change the number

Comment: Can i just ask what does 
(\(.*\))|(\D)","")*1
do?

Comment: *"Awesome thanks a lot! "*. You should accept the answer by  clicking on the [check sign ✓](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW82n.png) (which will go green) on the left of the answer. *"Can i just ask..."* Please read more about [how RE2 syntax works](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt). If still in need please let us know.

Comment: It looks like you accepted the other answer. Out of curiosity. Why? I any case. Glad I could help :)

Comment: The regular expression is `(\(.*\))|(\D)`: 2 x groups separated by "|" (Boolean OR). 1stGroup=`(\(.*\))` handles the brackets and all characters between them: "\(" and "\)" literally match "(" and ")", "." matches any character and the asterisk ("*") is a `Quantifier` that matches repetitively as many times as necessary: matches "(AR 0-19)". 2ndGroup=`(\D)` matches any character that's **NOT** a digit; this matches W,o,r,l,d,space,L,e,v,e,l,space. The unmatched value = `1` (a string) and the formula multiples by "1" to convert it to a number.

Answer (score 0):

In the interests of providing an (old-school) alternative. try this formula.

`=if(isna(A1),"",trim(mid(A1,search(" ",A1,search(" ",A1,1)+1)+1,search(" ",A1,search(" ",A1,search(" ",A1,1)+1)+1)-search(" ",A1,search(" ",A1,1)+1))))`

The logic is that the formula searches for the second and third space: the value between those two spaces being number value.